# Meaning of Null weights for GBM

Tags: r, machine-learning, gbm

I have a question about the weights parameter in `gbm`. It appears that setting weights to NULL and leaving it missing produce different results. If you consider the first example from the `gbm` documenation:

```
library(gbm)
set.seed(1986)
N <- 1000
X1 <- runif(N)
X2 <- 2*runif(N)
X3 <- ordered(sample(letters[1:4],N,replace=TRUE),levels=letters[4:1])
X4 <- factor(sample(letters[1:6],N,replace=TRUE))
X5 <- factor(sample(letters[1:3],N,replace=TRUE))
X6 <- 3*runif(N) 
mu <- c(-1,0,1,2)[as.numeric(X3)]

SNR <- 10 # signal-to-noise ratio
Y <- X1**1.5 + 2 * (X2**.5) + mu
sigma <- sqrt(var(Y)/SNR)
Y <- Y + rnorm(N,0,sigma)

# introduce some missing values
X1[sample(1:N,size=500)] <- NA
X4[sample(1:N,size=300)] <- NA

data <- data.frame(Y=Y,X1=X1,X2=X2,X3=X3,X4=X4,X5=X5,X6=X6)

# fit initial model with weight missing
gbm1 <-
  gbm(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6,         # formula
      data=data,                   # dataset
      var.monotone=c(0,0,0,0,0,0), # -1: monotone decrease,
      # +1: monotone increase,
      #  0: no monotone restrictions
      distribution="gaussian",     # see the help for other choices
      n.trees=1000,                # number of trees
      shrinkage=0.05,              # shrinkage or learning rate,
      # 0.001 to 0.1 usually work
      interaction.depth=3,         # 1: additive model, 2: two-way interactions, etc.
      bag.fraction = 0.5,          # subsampling fraction, 0.5 is probably best
      train.fraction = 0.5,        # fraction of data for training,
      # first train.fraction*N used for training
      n.minobsinnode = 10,         # minimum total weight needed in each node
      cv.folds = 3,                # do 3-fold cross-validation
      keep.data=TRUE,              # keep a copy of the dataset with the object
      verbose=FALSE,               # don't print out progress
      n.cores=1) 
# fit model with weight set to null
gbm2 <-
  gbm(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6,         # formula
      weights=NULL,                # extra weight parameter
      data=data,                   # dataset
      var.monotone=c(0,0,0,0,0,0), # -1: monotone decrease,
      # +1: monotone increase,
      #  0: no monotone restrictions
      distribution="gaussian",     # see the help for other choices
      n.trees=1000,                # number of trees
      shrinkage=0.05,              # shrinkage or learning rate,
      # 0.001 to 0.1 usually work
      interaction.depth=3,         # 1: additive model, 2: two-way interactions, etc.
      bag.fraction = 0.5,          # subsampling fraction, 0.5 is probably best
      train.fraction = 0.5,        # fraction of data for training,
      # first train.fraction*N used for training
      n.minobsinnode = 10,         # minimum total weight needed in each node
      cv.folds = 3,                # do 3-fold cross-validation
      keep.data=TRUE,              # keep a copy of the dataset with the object
      verbose=FALSE,               # don't print out progress
      n.cores=1)
summary(gbm1,1)
summary(gbm2,1)
```

The results of these two models are different, but it isn't clear to me why. What is the difference in meaning between NULL and missing weights for `gbm`?

Kind Regards

Comment: `gbm uses the R random number generator so set.seed can ensure that the model can be reconstructed`

Comment: Edited to include `set.seed`.

Comment: no, it means to use a seed when _fitting_ the model (although it is also always good to set a seed when generating the test data)

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks that answered my question.

Comment: Don't know much about R, but I do know there's some confusion between NA and NULL in the R language. Could that be the answer you're looking for? Perhaps it's set to NA?